# MySQL Insert slows down with 150mln records table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with logs (around 150mln records per day), when the database has less than 50 million records, inserts executed in around 1-2 seconds, but now I have 150 million records, one record takes around 7000 seconds  ss->http://scr.hu/1det/m3xrg

And I queue insert, for example, if `arrayList` has more than 150 elements or last flush was 5 seconds ago, I make one big query like:

```
INSERT INTO 'table' (firstColumn,secondColumn,etc) VALUES (firstValues) (Second values);
```

It is not a hardware problem because my database has 50gb cache, and has an SDD (dedicated server on ovh)

I changed in MySQL config auto-increment to random numbers, so I don't have ids like 1,2,3,4 but i have 1,10,230,555,etc.

So what should I change? I am thinking about mondodb because it is better for large databases?

Comment: 150 million records per day sounds pretty massive for a SQL database.  You might want to look into things like OrientDB which can support very large stores with lookup times which scale.

Comment: Have you tried `INSERT IGNORE`?

Comment: Cwallenpoole i think INSERT IGNORE can't speedup my insert cuz iso only ignore errors like "ON DUPLICATE KEY" i will try use mongo db :)